# Bring the app to foreground and if it is already running rather than creating new instance of it in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I want to launch apps(messaging,contacts,etc)if my launched app(messaging,contacts,etc) is already running in background I want it to bring front.I tried using `moveTaskToFront()` but it doesn't implement from above API 23(Lollipop).So,I ended up with this code:

```
Intent intent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.mms");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

By using this code if I launch a messaging from inside my app it launches,and if I again launches the same app from inside my app it perfectly resumes it and continue from where we left it.
But when I Launches the same messaging app from my default android launcher it just create new instance of messaging app on above of my already running messaging app which was already launched by my app.
I don't know what the solution for this.Please help me ...

Comment: Have you heard of [Activity Launch modes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) ?

Comment: @SlashG Yes I have tried it but it also create new instance

Comment: if you set android:launchMode="singleInstance" inside the <activity> tag, it doesn´t create a new instance......but only for your activity...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Yes you are right,but I want to launch an app not an activity.Do you know any solution

Comment: I am not sure if it belongs also to other apps if they are started via intent, but try `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` without `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: OK I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Use the below approach to invoke intents within your app like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CONTEXT, TARGET_ACTIVITY.CLASS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is completely restarting the app from beginning:(

Comment: The above code is useful inside your own app, like you want to fire same activity from notification, but AFAIK if you call `Explicit Intents`, it creates a separate call to the base Activity of the called Intent thus resulting in another instance of same application.

Comment: @Nitin_Misra then how we can stop creation of separate instance on the same application. Is it possible to bring the background app to foreground by using moveTaskToFront() in lollipop